# What is "Developer name" in shoutem login?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I started using shoutem.
`shoutem login` needs Developer name, but I have never register Developer name to shoutem. What should I input?

`` Enter developer name.
? Developer name # ← I don't know what should I input.
Access denied, use `shoutem login` command to login ``

Answer (score 1):

In normal case, user who do not have developer name can register developer name when login first.
However, user who made account by Facebook fail to first login on cli because they do not have password.
So, register password by "forget password" and retry from cli.